# What does E_n mean

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, machine-learning, expected-value

I came across the following symbol in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.09953.pdf) paper:

[image]

I am a little bit confused by the symbol [image]. Does it simply mean population average?

Comment: Now asked at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/407634/what-does-e-n-mean.